# clips_array ruins MoviePy performances

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I'm having the issue described in the title. here's an example :

```py
satisfying = VideoFileClip(f'satis/{random.randint(1, 5)}' + '.mp4', audio=False).subclip(rand, rand+(end-start)) # rand is already defined as an random value at which the video begins
video = clips_array([[video], [satisfying]]) # video is defined previously
 
await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: video .write_videofile(video_path.replace(".mp4", "") + ".captioned.mp4", codec="libx264", fps=24, preset='ultrafast', audio_codec='aac')) # loop and video-path are already defined
```

I'm using MoviePy 1.0.3 and usually reaching around 80it/s, but for some reason I only get a maximum of 7 or 8 it/s when using clips_array.

Is there any workaround or way to avoid this kind of issue please ? I'm already rendering in ultrafast and lowering the fps to 24, but the performances are still 10 times lower than the usual.

Thank you for your help.